# Does the software codes on dreamspark expire?

Tags: dreamspark

Also does anyone know when will my student account expire? Do I get to keep the codes after?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sign in, Go to "Your Account/Orders" and then "Your Eligibility". It'll show you when your subscription expires.

Update: My subscription for my student account recently expired so I can confirm that I can't access the MSDN-AA storefront anymore. Of course my installed software is still functioning. Just make sure you write down your codes somewhere.

Comment: The software will still continue to work, but I believe there's a clause that says you won't be able to access the order/keys after it expires.